# Set registry key to open notepad++

Tags: powershell

I tried running this script using the ISE, and I also tried to run it on the command line as administrator. It freezes at the "Remove-ItemProperty" line. I've tried to remove that step, but then it freezes at the next step "Set-ItemProperty". It looks like the New-Item lines are working fine.

```
if (Test-path "HKCR:\")
{
}
else
{
    New-PSDrive -Name HKCR -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
}

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
function Unzip
{
    param([string]$zipfile, [string]$outpath)

    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($zipfile, $outpath)
}

Unzip "npp.6.7.5.bin.zip" “C:\Notepad++”

New-Item -Type String "HKCR:\*\shell\Open With Notepad++"
New-Item -Type String "HKCR:\*\shell\Open With Notepad++\command"
Remove-ItemProperty "HKCR:\*\shell\Open With Notepad++\command" -name "(Default)"
Set-ItemProperty "HKCR:\*\shell\Open With Notepad++\command" -name "(Default)" -value "C:\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe %1"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Modifying `HKCR` is going to have unpredictable results because that hive is a merged view of `HKCU\Software\Classes` and `HKLM\Software\Classes`.  I'd pick one or the other (i.e., where ever the keys actually exist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `ItemProperty` commands it interprets * as a wildcard. It's not freezing, it's searching every subkey of HKCR for "shell\Open With..." etc.

To force it to interpret the whole thing as a string path you need to use the -LiteralPath switch:

```
New-Item -Type String "HKCR:\*\shell\Open With Notepad++"
New-Item -Type String "HKCR:\*\shell\Open With Notepad++\command"
Set-ItemProperty -LiteralPath "HKCR:\*\shell\Open With Notepad++\command" -name "(Default)" -value "C:\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe %1"
```

Comment: Hit that little snag myself trying to add an Open With Notepad option to a bunch of servers =P If this worked for you please mark it as the accepted answer